# How to download Oracle.DataAccess for .Net without an Oracle Account

Tags: .net, database, oracle

I need Oracle.DattaAccess on a .Net application but at the official download page found by Googling is requiring an Oracle account. Is there some way to donload an official release without an Oracle Account?

Comment: why you dont want to create an oracle account ? as its free

Comment: @Moudiz I won't use any Oracle service to need an account.

Comment: @Moudiz I don't mind creating a free account for a download, giving email, login and password. But they are requesting job title, work phone, company name, address, zip code.

Comment: well when i created an account to install the oracle database i didnt provide correct information and it works.

Comment: you can use an anon email account, and you only have to share what you want to

Comment: Oracle's Tom Kyte pointed out a long while ago that you need a free account for Microsoft SQL Servers Documentation, too. And he would of course have such an account, and, of course, not under his real name :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to have an Oracle account to download much of their software that is free to use.  Just provide the information you wish (of course a valid email is required) but no need to provide company information as Oracle has many independent developers that need to access Oracle products that are free to use, and documentation for all its products.

Answer (score 1):

```
official release without an Oracle Account
```

"Nothing is impossible, except skiing through a revolving door."

Your problem seems to be definitive. If you want Officiality you're gonna have to comply. If you simply want the binary, there are many many ways, but you know this already ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core

`Install-Package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core -Version 2.19.70`

[nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core/2.19.70](http://nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core/2.19.70)